# Excel query an Access select query to a secured Access DB

Tags: excel, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010, oledb

I apologize if the title is a bit confusing, let me explain.  Part of my work is processing / tagging large datasets from an ERP system and make it more meaningful for reporting purposes.  I use 2010 access databases to manipulate and tag data to regularly create static datasets user can point excel pivot tables to, this allows them to create reports for their clients.

We have had many issues of users using the default excel connection which is a [Share Deny Write] OLEDB connection.  This locks the "source" .accdb, preventing us from dropping an updated source.accdb file if any one of the dozens of users has their excel report open after refreshing their file.

To get around this, I found creating a "shadow" .accdb which simply contains linked tables or queries that query the source.accdb, these connections do not lock the source.accdb allowing us to overwrite the file with updated data as we please.

Some users still seek out the source.accdb and link directly to it, so we are trying to password protect them to prevent this.  I have no issues creating a select from the shadow.accdb to query the source.accdb using the proper password.  The problem arises when I try to link to any of the queries in the shadow.accdb from excel, I am thrown an "invalid password" error.

The issue seems to be the excel oledb (or odbc) connection is not being passed the password from the SQL query inside the shadow.accdb?

Yes, I understand this is a backasswards way of setting up data sources, but there are to many users to police the connections, I have no option of changing the programs we use, and there is no way from the database end to kill an excel connection to an access db, and so this is what I have to work with.

While I doubt anyone has specific experience with this setup, any ideas would be great.  An example of the connections from shadow.accdb to source.accdb is below:

```
SELECT *
FROM table IN '' [MS Access;PWD=password;DATABASE=C:\directory\Source.accdb];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `Mode = Share Deny None` instead of `Share Deny Write`, this should allow you to open and modify the access file while users are connected to it with the excel files, obviously they must update the data for get the last ones you added while they were connected to the DB.
You can do this specifyng the property `Share Deny None` while you are creating the connection in the tab *advanced* or you can edit an existing connection opening its properties, tab *definition*, and edit the connection string replacing `Mode = Share deny Write` with `Mode = Share Deny None`.

Comment: I cannot control the type of inbound connection to the databases (would be nice) so while I myself would never set it to read only, I can not stop other users from doing so.

Comment: In this case i can't help you...sorry